# Datomic aggregates usage

Tags: datomic, datalog

I want to find persons with minimal age with next query

```
(d/q '[:find ?name (min ?age)
         :in [[?name ?age]]]
       [["John" 20]
        ["Bill" 25]
        ["Jack" 20]
        ["Steve" 28]
        ["Andrew" 30]])
```

But result is

```
[["Andrew" 30] ["Bill" 25] ["Jack" 20] ["John" 20] ["Steve" 28]]
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 5):

This would be a pure Datalog solution

```
(let [db [["John" 20]
          ["Bill" 25]
          ["Jack" 20]
          ["Steve" 28]
          ["Andrew" 30]]]
  (d/q '[:find ?name ?min-age
         :in $ ?min-age
         :where [?name ?min-age]]
       db
       (ffirst (d/q '[:find (min ?age)
                      :in [[?name ?age]]]
                 db))))
```

A HAVING clause like in SQL is not part of the query language, but since all queries are executed in the peer, there is no overhead in doing nested queries.

Comment: I did the same as a solution. But 2 queries is bad in my opinion. Is it real to do it with one pure query?

Comment: It depends what you consider 'bad'. If it means a lot of code, you can use the solution by @user1641001 (replacing first with take-while). If it means 'bad' in the sense that this would be bad for query performance like it would be when using SQL, it's not the case, since your query is run locally in the peer.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of chaining the queries together, you could use a subquery (query call from within the query instead of outside of it):

```
(d/q '[:find ?name ?mage
       :in $
       :where [(datomic.api/q '[:find (min ?age)
                                :where [_ :age ?age]]
                              $) [[?mage]]]
              [?name :age ?mage]]
   [["John" :age 20]
    ["Bill" :age 25]
    ["Jack" :age 20]
    ["Steve" :age 28]
    ["Andrew" :age 30]])
```

Returns:

```
#{["John" 20] ["Jack" 20]}
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't need datomic in this case, as you already have in your sequence all the data needed. Use clojure **sort** instead.

```
(first (sort-by second [...]))
```