# Subquery support in datomic

Tags: datomic, datalog

Does datomic support subqueries or can those be simulated within a query? That would essentially be a `:find` within another `:find`.

I'm trying to perform analytical transformations of data in the query/DB itself rather than in the application.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: A SQL example is like  
[select id, len
  from (select id, length(foo) as len from user) as t;]
So I can create nested tables with an inner select and have transformations in the external select.

Comment: Do you use the Peer API or the Client API?

Comment: I wanted to use the Rest API (which is deprecated.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can issue a 'subquery' in Datomic. 
An example is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30771949/4480624).

It's also worth noting that because the work of query happens in your peer (assuming you're using the Peer API), there is not the same "n+1 problem" penalty for issuing two separate queries as you would have with a traditional RDB. So in addition to the sub-query approach, you could also issue the 'inner' query first, then pass the results from it as parameters to the 'outer' query.

-Marshall

Comment: I was hoping for a single query rather than multiple query calls from a client.

Comment: As that answer shows, you can call `datomic.api/q` inside a datalog clause to create a 'subquery' within your outer query.